# how do you pass a list of strings as conditions for np.select() in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list pf conditions `(" df['sample'].gt(0) & df['sample'].le(92666) , df['sample'].gt(92667) & df['sample'].le (92734)")`
choices is also a list `("4444", "5555")`
Now when i use `df['newsample'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)`
I keep getting error `"TypeError : invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray"`

But when i type the conditions in manually it works, the issue seems to be related to quotes when i use the list as array for condlist, how can i get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions need to result in a boolean array.  Something like

```
conditions = [ df['sample'] > 0, df['sample']<92666 ...]
```

What you have passed is a set of strings.  These aren't evaluated as part of the call to np.select statement.

Comment: yes my question was do i convert these strings to boolean if possible by deleting the tuples it generated

Answer (score 0):

```
(" df['sample'].gt(0) & df['sample'].le(92666) , df['sample'].gt(92667) & df['sample'].le (92734)")
```

This is a string - see the `""`.  The outer `()` don't add anything to the expression.

```
("4444", "5555")     # tuple of strings
[4444, 5555]           # list of numbers
```

is a tuple with 2 strings.  For this use, a tuple and list are valid

If you typed:

```
choices = (df['sample'].gt(0) & df['sample'].le(92666) , df['sample'].gt(92667) & df['sample'].le (92734))
```

and then did a

```
print(choices)
```

you should see a tuple with 2 boolean valued dataframes.

I think you need to read some more Python basics, along with your `panads` reading.  Python syntax and objests like lists, strings, tuples are just as important as pandas objects like dataframe and series.

Comment: i agree with you, but the problem i have is that the previous function i used to get to list of conditions make it a list of strings instead of conditions, is there a way to convert that list of strings to boolean conditions so i can use np.select?

Comment: @NandeepDevendra, strings have to be parsed or evaluated.  The `numpy` function cannot do that for you.